# Add values to a table from a second table that only match a third table allowing for duplicates

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I have been tasked to match a payment file from a bank that has invoices/payments listed on a text file I have imported into a table called Bank.  I need to match the invoices to the project/projects that are associated with the invoices - call this table Invoices - which contains every invoice and project we have every had.  I want to match the invoices (from Bank) to the project or multiple projects (from Invoices) to another table - called Report - so I can reconcile the payment file.  I can get the correct results from Bank and Invoices with the following query

```
SELECT invoice
FROM Invoices INV
INNER JOIN Bank as BANK
ON INV.Invoice = BANK.Invoice_Number
```

The Bank file has 100 invoices and I get 169 invoices on this query.  But when I try and do and update or insert

```
Update Report
set Invoice_Num = 
(SELECT invoice
FROM Invoices INV
INNER JOIN Bank as BANK
ON INV.Invoice = BANK.Invoice_Number)
```

I get 0 rows updated.

I have tried to copy the Bank table to the Report table with

```
Insert into Report(Invoice_Num)
select Invoice_Number from Bank
```

but can't figure out how to account for the projects that have duplicated invoices when they are found.  Of course I might be going at this entirely wrong and someone has a better way entirely.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us sample data, and the result that you want. It is not clear what you want to do with projects that have multiple invoices. Also, what is table `report`, that you want to update?

Comment: My apologies - I have to scrub the data due to data rules so it has to be generic.  Let say we have Invoice 001.  Invoice 001 is list in the Bank file with a payment of $1000.  Invoice 001 is listed in the Invoice table with projects 100 (invoice total $500) and project 101 (Invoice total $500).  I want to pull and match the the invoice and payment from the Bank file and match it with the two (or more) entires from the Invoice table in another table named Reports.The Reports table is one I have created to do the matching and data manipulation - currently blank.

Comment: [edit] your clarifications into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Report table have anything in to start with? If not, your UPDATE statement will update 0 rows, because there are 0 rows there to update. (Also, with your code as it stands, note that it would update every entry there to have the same, indeterminate value; I don't think that's what you intend.)

If you just want to copy the invoice numbers from Bank to Report, but leave out any duplicates, then your final bit of SQL just needs a DISTINCT added to do that:

```
Insert into Report(Invoice_Num)
select DISTINCT Invoice_Number from Bank
```

If you're trying to put in only invoice numbers from Bank that also match Invoice, then your first bit of code almost works, but needs to be an INSERT, not an UPDATE:

```
INSERT INTO report (invoice_number)
SELECT invoice
FROM Invoices INV
INNER JOIN Bank as BANK
ON INV.Invoice = BANK.Invoice_Number
```

Again, if you're also dealing with potential duplicates invoice numbers you only want in Report once, make that a SELECT DISTINCT to avoid them.

Comment: The Insert is what I needed.  I do want the duplicates but I managed to figure out the process.